# Is there a Zsh-like path replacement in Fish shell?

Tags: fish

I'm trying out **Fish** shell in OS X and was wondering if there's the same kind of path replacement functionality as I believe there is in **Zsh**, i.e.

```
user@machine ~> % cd /usr/www/site1/current/log
user@machine /usr/www/site1/current/log
%> cd site1 site2
/usr/www/site2/current/log
user@machine /usr/www/site2/current/log
%>
```

The example is taken - and customized - from the SlideShare [Why Zsh is Cooler than Your Shell](http://www.slideshare.net/jaguardesignstudio/why-zsh-is-cooler-than-your-shell-16194692).

I tried that in Fish but it doesn't seem to work, at least using the same syntax. I haven't found anything with "path replacement" in Fish documentation, either.

Comment: You'll find that fish is very nice for colors and tab completion, but it does not have many of these kinds of features: http://fishshell.com/docs/current/design.html

Answer (score 5):

Apparently Fish doesn't support path replacement out of the box.

I solved the problem by creating a simple custom function in `~/.config/fish/functions`called `cd.fish`:

```
function cd
    if test (count $argv) -eq 2
            builtin cd (echo $PWD|sed -e "s/$argv[1]/$argv[2]/")
    else
            builtin cd $argv
    end
end
```

This is probably not perfect for anyone who is used to Zsh but does make the example in the question work.

Note: Fish has its own version of the `cd` function already, so it's better to make this part of Fish's out-of-the-box version than replace it completely. This is only a partial example for clarity.